# Using AudioListener.GetSpectrumData will not work on particle system script

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

Using  `AudioListener.GetSpectrumData` to get an audio spectrum to use to modulate the Max Particles in a particle system. I use this exact method with other parts of my sketch to modulate the intensity of Lighting, the size of Cubes, Spheres, and Text...) but this will not work on the Particle System. Any ideas?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Max_Particles_Blow_Spectrum : MonoBehaviour {
[Range(1.0f, 30000.0f)]
public float phi = 0.0f;
private ParticleSystem ps;
void Start()
{
   ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
}

void Update()
{

    float[] phi = AudioListener.GetSpectrumData(1024, 0, FFTWindow.Hamming);
    var main = ps.main;
    float amplitude = Mathf.RoundToInt(phi[1]) ;
// i thought it was an issue with the float array to I tried converting it to an int
    main.maxParticles = Mathf.RoundToInt(amplitude);
}
void OnGUI()
{
   phi = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(25, 25, 100, 30), phi, 1f, 30000.0f);
}
}
```

Comment: try first declaring your array: float[] phi = new float[1024]; 
AudioListener.GetSpectrumData(phi, 0, FFTWindow.Hamming);

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting no Audio Spectrum readings